# Toggle Mute Javascript Function with Jquery Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi All I am trying to write both an if/else statement along with toggling an image. Basically my goal is to toggle an image (in this case with an id of soundonoff). However I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong. The issue is the toggle works, but the detect of whether its muted or not does not work. (In my full code for example I have it switch `innerHTML` of various audio/video files, this is where `document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0]` comes in. Any help would be tremendously appreciated I have spent about 4 hours working on this and can't seem to figure it out.

I should add that I do not know where to add an eventlistener for `detectmute()`, I tried to add it to my video, and to the button soundonoff but neither got working yet.

Here is my code:

```
function detectmute(){
if(document.getElementById('soundonoff').src == 'images/icons/soundoff.png'){
document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0].muted = true;
}
else if(document.getElementById('soundonoff').src == 'images/icons/soundon.png'){
document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0].muted = false;
}
$("#soundonoff").toggle(function(){
this.src = "images/icons/soundoff.png";
document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0].muted = true;
}, function() { 
this.src = "images/icons/soundon.png";
document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0].muted = false;
});
}
```

Comment: What's the initial state of your media (muted or not)? Checking the source value of an `img` tag probably isn't a good way to determine a state, especially since that source value is what's changed with your toggle. Can you provide the HTML markup?

Comment: Please post the answer *as* an answer; then it can be accepted and the question considered solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved my own issue, Solution was the following:

```
$("#soundonoff").toggle(function(){
 this.src = "images/icons/soundoff.png";
document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0].muted = true;
$("#soundonoff").attr('name', 'soundoff'); 
 }, function() { 
  this.src = "images/icons/soundon.png";
 document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0].muted = false;
 $("#soundonoff").attr('name', 'soundon'); 
   });

  function detectmute(){
      var soundstate = document.getElementById('soundonoff');
      if (soundstate.name == "soundon")
        {
      document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0].muted = false;
      }
  else if (soundstate.name == "soundoff")
      {
      document.getElementsByName('mymedia')[0].muted = true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#soundonoff').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('src') == 'images/icons/soundon.png') {
        $this.attr('src', 'images/icons/soundoff.png').attr('data-muted', true);
    } else {
        $this.attr('src', 'images/icons/soundon.png').attr('data-muted', false);
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jLvZW/3/ **updated**

You could also setup an object that converts one source to another:

```
var convert = {
        'images/icons/soundon.png' : ['images/icons/soundoff.png', true],
        'images/icons/soundoff.png' : ['images/icons/soundon.png', false]
    };
$('#soundonoff').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('src', convert[$this.attr('src')][0]).attr('data-muted', convert[$this.attr('src')][1]);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jLvZW/2/ **Updated**

Comment: This doesn't address the question, though. OP's problem was regarding his/her _detection_ mechanism, which probably indicates a fundamental design problem. I asked for clarification above.

Comment: @PiersMainwaring I added code to store the state in the `data-muted` attribute for both of my examples. If you watch the image element in your developer console you can see the `data-muted` attribute toggle with the source.

Comment: @ Jasper I think I said you rock a bit too soon, the issue was that it broke under jquery 1.4.4 (well broke my other stuff at least if I upgraded to 1.7 which I should do eventually anyways. I posted my solution in the original post, whats strange is that the same thing with .src reading wasn't working but if I do it by name it works perfectly.